# Crear un marco de datos de múltiples índices a partir de un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, diccionarios

Estoy tratando de transformar un diccionario de `datos`, accesible [aquí](https://jsonkeeper.com/b/IP3L), en un marco de datos de múltiples índices porque los valores de "datos" son en sí mismos diccionarios cuyos valores están en los diccionarios. Excepto algunas claves que quiero excluir.

```
>>> f = open('data/scores_attributes.json')
>>> data = json.load(f)
>>> data
>>> keys_attributes = keys_attributes - ['note', 'TotalResults'] # excluando las keys que no estan diccionarios.
>>> d = {}
>>> for k in data.keys():
...     for j in keys_attributes:
...         d[k][j] =  data[k][j]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'Her - Eau de Parfum'
```

Como pueden verlo obtengo esta keyerror ... Entonces, como crear un marco de datos de múltiples índices a partir de un diccionario?

Answer (score 1):

El código sería el siguiente:

```
import json
with open('data/scores_attributes.json') as data_file:    
    d = json.load(data_file)  
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in d.items()})
df = df.unstack(0)
df = df.swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
df
```

La principal función es la que extrae cada diccionario individual y del JSON, luego lo transforma en DataFrame(marco de datos) y lo concatena(lo une) a pedazos para poder saca el indice múltiple.

Se usa la función .unstack para cambiar los indices por jerarquía, es decir por nombres principales.

Luego de que se tiene el DataFrame por nombres se tiene que cambiar los indices multiples también por eso se usa la función .swaplevel, también se podría con .reorder_levels pero se ve mejor con .swaplevel. y al final con .sort_index terminamos de ordenar los indices.

Si quieres leer más sobre la función .unstack te dejo el enlace:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Saludos y buen día!